# IE 8 creates Empty Text Node for img tag

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

When i try to add a `<img>` tag, IE8 automatically add a '**Empty Text Node**' after the image tag.

**HTML :-**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Railway Services</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="img/logo.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="page" class="homePage">
       <div id="wrapper">
          <h1>Home Page</h1>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
      <div id="wrapper">
            <p class="copyRight">Copyright&#169;2012 Railway Services. All rights reserved</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**styles.css :-**

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
body{
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
   font-size:12px;
   color:#123456;
   font-family:verdana,_sans,arial;
   text-align:center;
}
#wrapper{
   width:98%;
   margin:0 auto;
}
#page{
   float:left;
   width:100%;
}
p{
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
}

/**********************HEADER*********************/

#header{
   float:left;
   width:100%;
}
.logo{
   float:left;
   width:20%;
   height:150px;
   cursor:pointer;
}
.logo img{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}

/************************HEADER END***************/

/************************FOOTER*******************/

#footer{
   float:left;
   width:100%;
}

/***********************FOOTER END****************/
```

**See this image**

[image: in IE8 console]

In the above image you can see the IE generates **Empty Text Node** after the `<img>` tag.

I can't found why IE generate empty text node.Can anybody help me..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a line break and some whitespace for indentation after the image tag, which leads to creating an empty text node.

If you write your code like that:

```
<div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"/></div>
```

you will not have the empty text node any more.

Since it's really IE specific, I think it's just a bug of the parser.

Answer (score 3):

IE shows this to any elements in the page that has a blank space between tags. This may not cause any problem.

The only consideration is when your content is inline and it adds a space between the elements. In this case, all you have to do is eliminate the blank space between the tags.